# Integration of razorpay payment gatway with django application

Tags: django, razorpay

I am a beginner in django and i want to integrate razorpay with django application but not getting any proper documentation
can anyone help me to provide step by step documentation or any github link.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-python
```

no there isn't any the only thing you can do now is to follow the guide from official website and make your own the needed steps for the python integration is given in the link